# Ubuntu software cannot install some programs

Tags: software-installation, 20.04, vlc, minecraft, ubuntu-store

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and when I open Ubuntu Software and click to install a program, it gives me this error:

[image: error while installing an app]

(Visual Studio Code is an example.)

this happens to the programs like `mc-installer` (minecraft installer) too. but always this command will install the program:

```
sudo snap install program-name
```

But sometimes I don't know the name of a program in command line. Something like Visual Studio Code. The next problem is: Ubuntu Software doesn't tell me the error! After the "cannot perform the following tasks:: is the end of the alert!

But sometimes graphical way can install some programs, such as VLC Media Player.

How can I do to fix the error of ubuntu software?

Answer (score 0):

For example, VSCode has the snap package name `code`.
But when using `apt` or `apt-get` some programs may be for older Ubuntu versions,
but still show up because they are in the repositories.